# Como pegar um arquivo JSON e decodificar em C++ ? ler o arquivo Json em C++

Tags: json, c++

Tenho um arquivo `JSON` com os dados dos funcionários e desejo ler esse arquivo em `C++` para passar `para` um pendrive e exportar esse arquivo, como proceder? 
Segue arquivo `JSON:`

> ":"Alexandre  N. da
>   C.Neves","ID":"213","PIS":"00000000","Tempo":1456229448}...

e o programa em C++ mais ou menos isso:

```
typedef struct  funcionario // struct com 100 elementos
{
    char CodBarras[11];
    char BioDados[512];
    char Passwd[11];
    char MiFareDado[21];
    char Nome[53];
    char ID[11];
    char PIS[13];
    char Aux[5];
    long int Tempo;
}functionaries[100];   // array para rodar essa struct 100x
```

o programa tem que carregar o arquivo JSON e carregar na Struct.

obrigado desde já

Comment: Tem certeza que isso não é C?

Comment: isso é C mas preciso pegar o arquivo JSON, e carregar nessa Struct em C. ou seja ler o arquivo JSON.

Comment: É que você escreveu no título, nas tags e na descrição "C++" e não "C".

Comment: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp

Comment: Você pode utilizar/compilar um pouco de C++, ou é obrigado a ter o código inteiramente em C? Se for 100% em C vai dar muito mais trabalho; usando C++, você pode usar o JSONCPP como o @LuizVieira mencionou, para decodificar em um objeto Json::Value, e então popular a sua struct a partir dele.

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?